# DRF testing: instead of JSON an OrderedDict is returned

Tags: json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement tests for the Django Rest Framework.
Most of my tests pass and setting them up went smooth, but i'm having an issue now where an `assertEqual` never succeeds because it keeps comparing JSON with an OrderedDict.

I have no idea where the OrderedDict comes from since DRF *should* only return JSON (right?).

Might it be possible that the testing environment is parsing the JSON before comparison? That would suck.

I'm doing an integrated test that only tests the data in the response of a GET request to a certain resource, I do this based on JSON fixtures. I'm not testing a specific component of the REST framework since my implementations of the components are so simple they're already tested by the tests in the DRF project.

Anyways, I hope someone can help me!

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. A serializer is responsible for converting your data into a dictionary, and it is the renderer that turns that into JSON. Which bit exactly are you testing?

Comment: Edited it! I already solved my problem, i had an issue in my fixtures. But i'm still curious why it compares an OrderedDict with JSON and not JSON with JSON so please answer if you have the time :)

Comment: If you need to ensure the order of the keys in your response JSON, then you can use OrderedDict to compose your response. As soon as it gets through he door and out in the wild it becomes a simple JSON, with keys in a specific order. Because you are using the Django testing infrastructure, your answer doesn't gets through the door, but instead is returned to your testcase to be inspected by you. Such behaviour makes possible to end up testing a dict (JSON) vs an OrderedDict. Normally this shouldn't be a problem: just assert on the individual keys.

Answer (score 13):

As explained [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#creating-test-requests), this is because the default format for requests during tests is `multipart` instead of `json`. You can specify the format by providing it to your api call like so:

```
response = self.client.get('/something/1', format='json')
```

Or you can set the default test request format in your `settings.py` like so:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json',  # Use application/json instead of multipart/form-data requests in tests.
}
```

To fix it for all your tests automagically.

Comment: I am not sure if this has changed since this answer, but the docs nowadays state that the `format='json'` argument only works for "Methods which create a request body", thus excluding `GET` requests. I can confirm this with my own code and also from reading the source code (as far as I can understand). Weirdly enough, there is an example in the doc where the `format` argument is passed to the `get()` method.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you're using response.data (which returns the parsed json objects) instead of response.content (which gives the raw json string).

See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#testing-responses

Answer (score 5):

If your tests look something like this:

```
class SomeTests(APITestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        response = self.client.get('/something/1')
        # assertions with response
```

Then response will certainly be an OrderedDict rather than a JSON document. Luckily Django 1.9 has introduced the `response.json()` method (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.json) so you can easily convert the response into JSON. Note that you could also use python's `json` library.

The catch here is that Django's test client (that DRF extends) is a "dummy browser" (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client) and doesn't work exactly like an in-browser framework such as Selenium would. Thus, HTTP calls are actually just simulated HTTP calls that focus on testing your logic and that correct routing/views/serializers/etc. are being used.

Answer (score 3):

You can dump your data into json format :

```
import json
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: @awwester if you are finding my answer helpful. kindlysupport me by upvoting. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by using [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

Simply, within the serializer class copy next last 3 lines and replace `result` with the json member that cause the problem

```
class ConfigSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Config
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'email', "result",)

    # COPY NEXT 3 LINES AND CHANGE 'result' WITH THE JSON MEMBER THAT CAUSE THE PROBLEM
    result = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_result(self, obj):
        return obj.result
```

Before the `result` shows as:

```
{result: "OrderedDict([('key1', 1), ('key2', OrderedDict([('key3', [1, 2, 3])]))])"}
```

After solution, `result` become:

```
{"result": {"key1":1,"key2":{"key3":[1,2,3]}}}
```

Comment: Awesome! That actually solved the issue for me!!